# PostgreSQL not triggering when NEW.field is NULL

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have the following trigger on my table of customers so I can track whether the customer name has been changed over time and what the previous versions of the name were.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_customer_changes_log_history() RETURNS trigger as 
$BODY$
    BEGIN
       IF (NEW.name <> OLD.name)  
    THEN
        INSERT INTO tbl_customers_history(customer_id, name, action)
        VALUES(OLD.id, OLD.name, 'UPDATE');
    END IF;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tr_customer_changes_log_history
BEFORE UPDATE ON tbl_customers
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_customer_changes_log_history();
```

But when I do an UPDATE when the NEW.name = NULL and and the OLD.name = "Customer 1" this trigger is not triggered? It only triggers when NEW.name has a actual string value here.

Why is that? NULL and "Customer 1" are not equal so it should trigger?

Answer (score 9):

Use

```
IF (NEW.name IS DISTINCT FROM OLD.name)
```

instead of

```
IF (NEW.name <> OLD.name)
```

Comment: How will this perform when comparing this to the already suggested answers with COALESCE?

Comment: There might be a few operations less, but I expect that there will be no measurable difference. I'd prefer my version though because it is easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the condition to

```
IF COALESCE((NEW.name <> OLD.name), true)
```

The problem is that if `NEW.field` is `NULL` then `NEW.name <> OLD.name` evaluates to `NULL` no matter what the value of `OLD.name` is. In a conditional, `NULL` is always treated as false.

A more correct answer would have been

```
IF COALESCE((NEW.name <> OLD.name), true) AND NOT (NEW.name IS NULL AND OLD.name IS NULL)
```

to take care of the case when both `NEW.name` and `OLD.name` are `NULL`, so that they are not treated as equal in that case.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But do you have any idea why it won't trigger as I did? Why this COALESCE stuff is necessary?

Comment: @koala I expanded my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL <> 'anything'` always evaluates to `FALSE`. Just like `NULL = 'anything'` or `NULL > 5`.

You need `coalesce` to fix the comparison:

```
COALESCE(NEW.name, '') <> COALESCE(OLD.name, '')
```